# Is it possible to configure the wizard in TCA so that I can create a new particular plugin?

Tags: typo3

How can I create a custom wizard in TCA so that, I can click on add button to  create a particluar specific plugin on a page? my TYPO3 Version is 7.6.
[click on the image. There is a add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR8tH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom wizard on your own or use an existing one. Here you can find examples of existing ones and an example to create a custom one: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/AdditionalFeatures/WizardsConfiguration/Index.html#user-defined-wizard-processing-with-php-function

Answer (score 0):

Note this code area has been rewritten with core v8 - much more powerful 'wizards' are possible, called 'node expansion' and they come with a better API. For details see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Rendering/Index.html#node-expansion and the according sections from TCA Reference for details.